# Migrating Spring Form based login from 3.x to 4.0 bean action not being executed

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have switched from Spring security 3.x to 4.0 and am now facing some issues with my custom login form.

My Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {CustomUserDetailsService.class, CustomPermissionEvaluator.class})
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Resource(name = "authService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
static class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler
                = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return handler;
    }

    public CustomPermissionEvaluator getPermissionEvaluator() {
        return permissionEvaluator;
    }

    public void setPermissionEvaluator(CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator) {
        this.permissionEvaluator = permissionEvaluator;
    }

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/pages/unsecure/**", "/layouts/**", "/resources/**", "/javax.faces.resource/**", "/uploads/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .deleteCookies()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();

}

@Autowired
public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder);
}
```

My CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("----------------"+login+"-------------------");
    com.redast.model.User domainUser = getUserDAO().findByLogin(login);
    if(domainUser == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find user"+login);
    }

    return new UserDAOUserDetails(domainUser);

}
```

My  LoginBean:

```
public String login() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Login Action: "+this.getUserName());

        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUserName(), this.getPassword());

        Authentication result = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        return "/pages/unsecure/login";
    }
    return "/pages/unsecure/welcomePage?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And finaly my Login Form:

```
 <h:form  id="loginFormId" prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="3" id="loginGrid">

                <h:outputLabel id="outTxtUserNameId" value="Username: " for="username"/>
                <p:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{loginMgmtBean.userName}" requiredMessage="Please enter username" label="Name"></p:inputText>
                <p:message for="username" />

                <h:outputLabel id="outTxtPasswordId" value="Password: " for="password"/>
                <p:password id="password"  required="true" value="#{loginMgmtBean.password}" requiredMessage="Please enter password"></p:password>
                <p:message for="password" />

                <p:commandButton id="btnLoginId" value="Login" action="#{loginMgmtBean.login}" styleClass="loginPanelBtn"  validateClient="true" update="loginGrid" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

My Problem is, that the click on `btnLoginId` executes the method `loadUserByUsername` directly in CustomUserDetailsService and not `login` in the Login Bean. This used to work with the old version. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Additionally I switched from XML based configuration to Java Based Configuration. So here is my **OLD** XML:

```
<!-- Enable method level Spring Security by annotations  -->
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>  
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /pages/secure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /pages/unsecure/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/unsecure/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /layouts/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/layouts/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /resources/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Permit access to resources in /uploads/** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/uploads/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Enable Primefaces -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Page level Spring Security : Intercept access to resources in /** -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>



    <!-- Define login page for Spring Security -->      
    <sec:form-login login-page="/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml"/>

    <!-- Define logout properties for Spring Security -->
    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml"></sec:logout>
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/pages/unsecure/error.xhtml" />
</sec:http>

<!-- Set customUserDetailsService class as the authentication Manager for Spring Security-->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder hash="bcrypt"></sec:password-encoder>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
            class="com.redast.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myPermissionEvaluator" name="myPermissionEvaluator" class="com.redast.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator">

</beans:bean>


<!-- Inject authentication Manager to our LoginBean -->
<beans:bean id="loginBean" name="loginBean" class="com.redast.managedController.LoginBean" scope="prototype">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Thanks.
bwright

Comment: I guess you have no bean for your LoginBean declared in your java config as you had done it in your xml config.

Comment: I'm rather new to both xml and java config. How would i go a bout in defining this bean?

Comment: You write a new method in your `@Configuration` annotated config class. That method has to be annotated with the `@Bean` annotation and has to return an instance of the bean. So the method signature would look like: `@Bean public LoginBean getLoginBean() {}`

Comment: Also you will have to declare an Authentication Manager

Comment: Isn't the `Authenticationmanager` defined/created in `registerAuthentication` in `WebSecurityConfiguration` ?

Comment: btw. i am using annotations for defining the beans. So my LoginBean is annotated with: `@ManagedBean(name = "loginMgmtBean")`

Comment: Yes you are right the AuthenticationManager is created there, i never used the AuthenticationManagerBuilder before though. Probably spring isn't creating the ManagedBean. can you add the LoginBean to your component scan and try again?

Comment: Ok it is working now. Not sure which change actually fixed the problem (i guess your last comment). Only thing that is not working is the redirect after successfull login (But that is a new problem i will fix). Thats why i don't know when it started working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `permitAll()` method call after `formLogin()` and `logout()` method calls:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/pages/unsecure/**", "/layouts/**", "/resources/**", "/javax.faces.resource/**", "/uploads/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml")
        .and()
    .logout()
        .deleteCookies()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/pages/unsecure/login.xhtml")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .disable();
```